# My egrep -x has stopped working? What would cause it?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I recently noticed my cron jobs that run these commands are no longer pulling off the egrep for specific length domain names in a list. I was using this prior:

```
egrep -ix '[a-z]{5}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt
```

Contents of cleanedcomlist.txt are now:

```
abcdf.com
acbdf.com
acdfg.com
acdff.com
notworking.com
```

This is my output:

```
$ rm -rf 5letter.txt
$ egrep -ix '[a-z]{5}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt
$ cat 5letter.txt
$
```

Notably, no output exists.

Sorry for the confusion. Was trying to show what I have tried.

Comment: Define "not working"? What do you get if you run that *exact* command yourself (not some vaguely similar command)?

Comment: None of those sample lines match `[a-z]{5}.com` as an entire line. They are all longer than five characters.

Comment: `aabbxs.com` should match for the `[a-z]{5,6}\.com` call to `grep`.

Comment: You have posted four different commands so far: `egrep -x` and `egrep -ix '[a-z]{5}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt` and `egrep '{5,6}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt` and `grep '[a-z]{5,6}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt`. Can you please pick ONE and edit your question, showing COMPLETE input and output (feel free to make a tiny "cleanedcomlist.txt" with only two lines in it so you can post the whole thing, this will make it easier for everyone)

Comment: Edited the original post to make it cleaner.

Comment: The original was still a bit of a mess -- better not to include shell prompts, since that content makes it harder to tell what's part of literal command output and what's part of a prompt.

Comment: I'd suggest getting this into a state (editing as necessary) where you can reproduce the problem yourself (and *have tested that* you can reproduce the problem yourself) copying-and-pasting from the question you ask here, not relying on any information you haven't presented. Until that's done, it's not really something anyone else is able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they don't work: This regular expression filters for names of length 5 (exactly), and none of your names are 5 letters! Change the expression to

```
egrep -ix '[a-z]{6}\.com'
```

...and output is properly emitted (for the six-character names) with the input file given.

Comment: I am doing terrible at this. I had it all working for over a year. I edited the original with the same output. The original cleanedcomlist.txt has roughly 100 or so LLLLL.com domains in it. This same egrep runs for 6 letter, 7 letter, and 8 letter and returns 0 byte files.

Comment: Miscounted. Now I have. 

egrep -ix '[a-z]{6}\.com' cleanedcomlist.txt >> 5letter.txt
wc 5letter.txt 0 0 0 5letter.txt

Comment: `LLLLL.com`? You realize that those are upper-case letters, and depending on your locale's collation order, the expression you're using now may work with lower-case only?

Comment: (This is part of why using anonymized data in asking StackOverflow questions is such a mess: We can't tell which mismatches are because of the anonymization process, and which mismatches are related to your actual problem).

Comment: If you want to work with both upper- and lower-case letters, by the way, change `[a-z]` to `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: Should -i change it to be non-case sensitive on the egrep?

Comment: Have you also checked your file type? If there are DOS line endings on your input file, that'll prevent anything from matching.